# Calling notifyDataSetChanged() outside of the Fragment it is in

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm writing an application that allows for the sharing of recipes. When one receives a recipe, they can save it to their phone and it will appear as a fragment of a list.
Problem is, when I save it, I get an IllegalStateException for not calling NotifyDataSetChanged(), which I can't find a way to do in the Activity that I am in. If anyone knows how I can find a way to get access to the adapter that calls this, that would be greatly appreciated. Making it static didn't seem to be an option.

```
    public class SmsViewActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "SmsViewActivity";
    private static final String SMS_FOOD = "food_recieved";
    private FoodJSONSerializer mSerializer;
    public Button mSaveButton, mDismissButton;
    public int mNotificationId;
    public String message;
    private EditText mTitleField;

    private EditText mServingsField;
    private EditText mDirectionsField;

    Food mFood;
    private String msg;
    private Activity mActivity;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "OnCreate");
        mActivity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_view);
        mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button_sms);
        mDismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dismiss_button_sms);

            // ------------------------------------------------------------

            // Get extras and display information in view
            //String sender = getIntent().getStringExtra("sender");
           this.msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonRecipe = new JSONObject(this.msg);
                this.mFood = new Food(jsonRecipe);

                Log.i(TAG, "Food = " + mFood);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
            mNotificationId = getIntent().getIntExtra("notificationid", 0);
            if (mNotificationId == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not retrieve notification ID.");
                Toast.makeText(this, "A fatal error has occurred in SMS viewer.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

            // Cancel the notification
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            notificationMgr.cancel(mNotificationId);

            // --------------------------------------------------
            this.mTitleField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.food_title_sms);
            this.mTitleField.setText(mFood.getTitle());

            this.mServingsField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.food_servings_sms);
            this.mServingsField.setText(Integer.toString(mFood.getServings()));

           this.mDirectionsField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.directions_text_sms);
            this.mDirectionsField.setText(mFood.getDirections());


            // --------------------------------------------------

            // Listener for Save button click
            this.mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FoodStorage.get(mActivity).addFood(mFood);
                    //NEED TO CALL notifyDataSetChanged(); HERE

                    finish();
                    } 
            });

            // Listener for Dismiss button click
            this.mDismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    backToList();
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }

        public void backToList() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, FoodListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


    }
```

Here is the Fragment where the adapter lives and where every other instance of adding or deleting occurs.

```
    public class FoodListFragment extends ListFragment{
    private ArrayList<Food> mFood;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.food_title);
        mFood = FoodStorage.get(getActivity()).getFood();
        FoodAdapter adapter = new FoodAdapter(mFood);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Use floating context menus on Froyo and Gingerbread

        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        } else {
            // Use contextual action bar on Honeycomb and higher
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                        long id, boolean checked) {
                    // Required, but not used in this implementation
                }

                // ActionMode.Callback methods
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.food_list_item_context, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                    // Required, but not used in this implementation
                }

                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_item_delete_food:
                            FoodAdapter adapter = (FoodAdapter)getListAdapter();
                            FoodStorage foodStorage = FoodStorage.get(getActivity());
                            for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                                    foodStorage.deleteFood(adapter.getItem(i));
                                }
                            }
                            mode.finish();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    // Required, but not used in this implementation
                }
            }); 
        }

        return v;
    } 

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // get the Food from the adapter
        Food c = ((FoodAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        // start an instance of CrimePagerActivity
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FoodPagerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(FoodFragment.EXTRA_FOOD_ID, c.getId());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    } 


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ((FoodAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_food_list, menu);
    } 


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_new_food:
                Food food = new Food();
                FoodStorage.get(getActivity()).addFood(food);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FoodPagerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(FoodFragment.EXTRA_FOOD_ID, food.getId());
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.food_list_item_context, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        int position = info.position;
        FoodAdapter adapter = (FoodAdapter)getListAdapter();
        Food food = adapter.getItem(position);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_delete_food:
                FoodStorage.get(getActivity()).deleteFood(food);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class FoodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {
        public FoodAdapter(ArrayList<Food> food) {
            super(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, food);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_food, null);
            }

            // configure the view for this recipe
            Food c = getItem(position);

            TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_list_item_titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());

            TextView servingsTextView =
                    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_list_item_servingsTextView);
                servingsTextView.setText("Makes " + c.getServings() + " servings");

                TextView ingredientsTextView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.food_list_item_ingredientsTextView);
                JSONArray j = c.jIngredients;

                String display = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        display = display + j.get(i) + "\n";
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // Do nothing.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                ingredientsTextView.setText("Ingredients:\n" + display);

            TextView directionsTextView = 
                    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_list_item_directionsTextView);
                directionsTextView.setText("Directions:\n " + c.getDirections());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you have instantiate the FoodListFragment? Try to write a public method to call the notifyDataSetChanged() and call the method where you adding the mFood data to the list. Before that make the FoodAdapter as public to access it in the method to update.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Eventbus from greenrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It provides you with a way to post events anywhere to any subscriber who can receive the event and call any method.

In the onCreate method of your fragment, call this `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);` to register your fragment as a subscriber.

Create a new method in your fragment: `public void onEvent(AnyEventType event) {}`. When an event is posted on the event bus, this method will be called. you may call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` in the onEvent method. AnyEventType can be just any class (can be a POJO). You may use this class to pass any info to your fragment.

In your activity, you can call `EventBus.getDefault().post(event);` to notify your fragment. The onEvent method in your fragment will be executed when the event is posted.

Refer to the EventBus readme for more info.